# Google maps not loading in android 6.0 in my ionic application

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, ionic-framework

Google map not loading in android 6.0(marshmallow) in ionic application. Working in device(android version lower than 6 ) and browser also. Tried updating cordova version and removing, adding platform didn't work. Also no errors are present while debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Based from this [thread](https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps/issues/1084), this [plugin](https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps/search?q=ionic&type=Issues&utf8=%E2%9C%93) works fine with Android 6.0.1. You can check it out. You can also follow this [tutorial](http://www.joshmorony.com/ionic-2-how-to-use-google-maps-geolocation-video-tutorial/). Maybe you missed some configurations.

Here are some related threads which might help:

- [Google maps not showing](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/google-maps-not-showing/20113/13)
- http://www.joshmorony.com/integrating-google-maps-with-an-ionic-application/

Comment: Thanks for your response but still no suitable solution.